# Natural language processing for hinglish tweets

Tags: nlp, textblob

I have used textblob to assign polarity score to english tweets.Can textblob be used to assign polarity score to Hinglish tweets?
If yes how?

Thankyou

Comment: Depends. It is impossible to answer without knowing more details. Just try it out and see what results you get.

Comment: i am trying to convert hinglish dataset to english language using googletrans.Can you please suggest me the piece of code i should use

Comment: I doubt that this is possible.

Comment: Then can you please suggest me how to do sentiment analysis of hinglish dataset.

Comment: Just pretend it is English data, and then see what you get. If it's not what you want, ask the question here again with examples.

Comment: i am describing the whole scenario.I have a dataset which is in Hinglish language.But i need to assign polarity score to each of the tweets using textblob.and for using textblob i need to convert all the tweets in english else textblob cant work properly in hinglish data.Can you please help me with the code or suggest me some other way to proceed .

Comment: When you say "can't work properly", what is the issue?

Comment: according to observation some of the tweets which should have polarity as -ve is given polarity score as positive or neutral.Most of the cases its assigned as neutral.i think its because some of the words which is to be used to assign the polarity is written in hindi

Comment: so i want to convert al the tweets in english,

Answer (score 3):

TextBlob is not that good a solution. You can first try to convert the Hinglish tweets into English using this notebook [here on GitHub](https://github.com/ashishjain1547/pubML/blob/main/e12_transformer_based_translation/Code/For%20hinglish%20to%20english%20translation.ipynb).

And then do some BERT based Sentiment analysis as shown in these webpages:

1. [survival8 Sep-2020](https://survival8.blogspot.com/2020/09/sentiment-analysis-using-bert.html)
2. [survival8 Sep-2022](https://survival8.blogspot.com/2022/09/sentiment-analysis-using-bert.html)

Also, checkout this link that compares three Sentiment Analyzers:

1. TextBlob
2. VADER
3. BERT Based Project.

[survival8: Sentiment Analysis Testing on Some Difficult Sentences](https://survival8.blogspot.com/2020/09/sentiment-analysis-testing-on-some.html)